# Form submits on keyup after validation, instead of onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is a JSFiddle which will show the issue that I am having.

Currently, form data gets submitted on keyup as soon as that data is validated, which it should really only submit data when the 'subscribe' button is clicked.

So the form should work like this. If a user clicks the subscribe button, and a particular input fails validation, then that error should be shown. If the user then corrects the error, that specific error should clear on keyup, however, the user should have to click 'subscribe' before the form actually submits any data, or checks for validation again. Currently, the form submits on keyup after passing validation and that should not be the case.

I want to know how I can validate (not submit data) on keyup, as well as validate on click, in addition to submitting data on click.

http://jsfiddle.net/cqf8guys/5/

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form #response2').hide();


$('.txt1').on('keyup click', function(e) {


e.preventDefault();

var valid = '';
var required = ' is required';
var first = $('form #first').val();
var last = $('form #last').val();
var city = $('form #city').val();
var email = $('form #email').val();
var tempt = $('form #tempt').val();
var tempt2 = $('form #tempt2').val();


if(first=='' || first.length<=1) {
    $('form #first').css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
    $('form #first').css('background-color','#ffcece');
    valid += '<p>Your first name is required</p>';
}
else {
  $('form #first').removeAttr('style');
}

if(last=='' || last.length<=1) {
    $('form #last').css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
    $('form #last').css('background-color','#ffcece');
    valid += '<p>Your last name' + required + '</p>';
}
else {
  $(this).removeAttr('style');
}

if(city=='' || city.length<=1) {
    $('form #city').css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
    $('form #city').css('background-color','#ffcece');
    valid += '<p>Please include your city</p>';
}
else {
  $('form #city').removeAttr('style');
}

if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
    valid += '<p>A valid E-Mail address is required</p>';
}

if (tempt != 'http://') {
    valid += '<p>We can\'t allow spam bots.</p>';
}

if (tempt2 != '') {
    valid += '<p>A human user' + required + '</p>';
}

if (valid != '') {
    $('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('error2')
        .html('' +valid).fadeIn('fast');
}

else {
    $('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('processing2').html('<p style="top:0px; left:0px; text-align:center; line-height:1.5em;">Please wait while we process your information...</p>').fadeIn('fast');

    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    submitFormSubscribe(formData);
}

});

});

function submitFormSubscribe(formData) {

$.ajax({

type: 'POST',
url: 'http://3elementsreview.com/blog/wp-content/themes/3elements/php-signup/sign-up-complete.php',
data: formData,
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
timeout: 4000,
success: function(data) {

$('form #response2').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error2' : 'success2')
          .html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');

if ($('form #response2').hasClass('success2')) {
setTimeout("$('form #response2').fadeOut('fast')", 6000);
}

},
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

$('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('error2')
.html('<p>There was an <strong>' + errorThrown +
'</strong> error due to an <strong>' + textStatus +
'</strong> condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');
},
complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {                    
$('form')[0].reset();
}   
});

};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have attached your functionality to the wrong event listener type. You don't want `$('.txt1').on('keyup click', function(e) {...` that's why it is getting mixed up when you deselect something. Instead you want the submit event listener like so....

`$('.txt1').on('submit', function(e) {...` or `$('.txt1').submit(function(e) {...`

then if the validation fails you can do an `e.preventDefault();` and no form submission will occur.

Here is an example not using your own code...

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var zipSwitch = false;

$(function() {
    zipValidate();
    validateForm(); //Add Form Submit Validation Event

});

//Constantly Monitor Validation
function zipValidate() {
    $("#zip").keyup(function() {
        var zipInput = $("#zip").val();

        if($.isNumeric(zipInput)) {
            $("#msgZone").html("Zip is correct");           
            $("#msgZone").attr("style", "border-color: rgb(4, 255, 17)");
            zipSwitch = true;

        } else {
            $("#msgZone").html("Zip must be numbers only. Please remove letters.");
            $("#msgZone").attr("style", "border-color: rgb(250, 20, 10)");
            zipSwitch = false;

        }

    });
}

//Allow Form To Submit or Not Depending on Validation
function validateForm() {
    $("#form1").submit(function(e) {

        //If Form Validation Was Correct
        if(zipSwitch==true) {

            var validCountry = countryValidationFunction();

            if(validCountry==true) {
                alert("Form Submitted Successfully");

            } else if(validCountry==false) {
                alert("Please Enter a Valid Country");
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });


 }
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="#" method="POST" class="span12" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div id="msgZone" class="well">
        Validation Message Zone
    </div>

    <div class="controls-row">                                                                      
        <span class="help-inline control-list">Zip:</span>
        <input id="zip" name="zip" type="text" class="input-medium" required="true" />
    </div>      
    <hr />


    <div class="controls-row">
        <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success" onSubmit="validateForm()">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <hr />

</form>
```